# import local file to google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I don't understand how colab works with directories, I created a notebook, and colab put it in /Google Drive/Colab Notebooks.

Now I need to import a file (data.py) where I have a bunch of functions I need. Intuition tells me to put the file in that same directory and import it with:

import data

but apparently that's not the way...

I also tried adding the directory to the set of paths but I am specifying the directory incorrectly..

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can upload your code to github and use git clone inside colab

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now google is officially providing support for accessing and working with Gdrive at ease.

You can use the below code to mount your drive to Colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive/My\ Drive/{location you want to move}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `!cd /gdrive/My\ Drive/{location you want to move}` not `%cd /gdrive/My\ Drive/{location you want to move}`

Comment: If you're using the same cell for both python code and shell scripting then use `%` for the shell commands. Else, you'll get an error.

`!` works only when there is shell script in the code cell.

Answer (score 20):

Colab notebooks are stored on Google Drive. But it is run on another virtual machine. So, you need to copy your data.py there too. Do this to upload data.py through Colab.

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
# choose the file on your computer to upload it then
import data
```

Comment: thanks, that worked well... and if I make changes to data.py locally, how do I update it in colab? I upload it again but it doesn't update... also, is there a way to edit .py files in colab?

Comment: You may need to delete the old version first with `!rm data.py`, then upload it again. You may need to `import importlib` and `importlib.reload(data)` too.

Comment: @Danf You can use the magic function `%load filename.py` to get the content of the file in the code cell and can edit it there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that... do you think that's better than using a Drive FUSE wrapper? I'm searching for the most efficient way of setting up my environment...

Comment: @AnkurAnkan Where should the file reside to be able to load it this way?

Comment: @user25004 It can be anywhere. `files.upload()` opens a dialog box to select the files you want to upload.

Comment: What If I have thousand of files to load and I want to do it automatically?

Comment: @Laura you can use zip/unzip to manage 1000 files in one go. Alternatives are: pydrive, git clone, and wget, if you really want it automatic.

Answer (score 12):

To easily upload a local file you can use the new Google Colab feature:

- click on right arrow on the left of your screen (below the Google
  Colab logo) [image]
- select Files tab
- click Upload button

It will open a popup to choose file to upload from your local filesystem.

Comment: It works fine, but each time we want to run the code we should upload it again. IS there any easier way to access the files?

Answer (score 6):

**To upload Local files from system to collab storage/directory.**

```
from google.colab import files
def getLocalFiles():
    _files = files.upload()
    if len(_files) >0:
       for k,v in _files.items():
         open(k,'wb').write(v)
getLocalFiles()
```

[image]

Comment: That works, but I found that linking Google drive with a wrapper is better if you need to handle lots of files that change constantly. All you need to do when something changes is restar the kernel.

Comment: Can you included that as a answer

Comment: Yes, I'll just have to find my code, since it's been a while and I stopped using colab since then...

Comment: Posted my answer and the tools I used!

Comment: Yes saw that method is also good. But my answer also could not be rejected as there are different approaches to same solution.

Comment: Definitely, your answer is a working solution. It's just that in my specific case that method would be impractical, while the wrapper provides a more "online" solution, fitting better in my case.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is how I finally solved this. I have to point out however, that in my case I had to work with several files and proprietary modules that were changing all the time.

The best solution I found to do this was to use a FUSE wrapper to "link" colab to my google account. I used this particular tool:

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

There is an example of how to set up your environment there, but here is how I did it:

```
# Install a Drive FUSE wrapper.
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse


# Generate auth tokens for Colab
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

At this point you'll have installed the wrapper and the code above will generate a couple of links for you to authorize access to your google drive account.

The you have to create a folder in the colab file system (remember this is not persistent, as far as I know...) and mount your drive there:

```
# Create a directory and mount Google Drive using that directory.
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive

print ('Files in Drive:')
!ls drive/
```

the *!ls* command will print the directory contents so you can check it works, and that's it. You now have all the files you need and you can make changes to them with no further complications. Remember that you may need to restar the kernel to update the imports and variables.

Hope this works for someone!

Answer (score 0):

you can write following commands in colab to mount the drive

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

and you can download from some external url into the drive through simple linux command wget like this

```
!wget 'https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset'
```